# "In the police station" or "at the police station"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say:

> **1.** I filed a complaint **in** the police station.

Or

> **2.** I filed a complaint **at** the police station.

Comment: *I met him in/at school/the shop/Cambridge*. Same difference.

Answer (score 2):

***At*** is the correct choice in this case.

The debates about "at vs in" never cease.

In this case, it would seem, "at" would indicate that the person is at a certain place performing a task, or tasks, characteristic of that place (such as filing a complaint). "In" would indicate that he or she popped into the police station on some business that isn't directly related to police matters.

A century ago folks used to say "I've just arrived at Paris," whereas now they say "I've just arrived in Paris."